# Ruby converting String to File for uploading to FTP

Tags: ruby, csv, ftp, stringio

Currently we have a method that returns a string with a formatted CSV file.

```
string   = EXPORT.tickets
```

We need to upload this csv file to a ftp server like so

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new(server, username, password)
ftp.putbinaryfile(string)
```

however, the `string` variable is obviously a string, and not a binary file as the putbinaryfile method expects. I see two ways to do this,

1. convert the `string` variable to a file first using `File`
2. convert the string directly to a file with something like `StringIO`

Do these seem like viable options? If so, how would I approach doing this, thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Since the putbinaryfile method is looking for a file path rather than an actual file, it looks like my best best will be to create a File from the `string` variable. Can anyone give an example of how this can be accomplished?

Comment: This is not 100%, `putbinaryfile` expects the PATH of a binary file (which could be a string). I would probably first create a File (see http://devdocs.io/ruby/file#method-c-new) and then upload it. Don't forget to delete the file after uploading it :)

Comment: You are correct, it is looking for the PATH. What do you think of me using the Ruby Tempfile class? http://devdocs.io/ruby/tempfile

Comment: Sounds good! One more thing: I THINK you can use `puttextfile` instead of `putbinaryfile`, as CSV is just text, but be sure to test this first...

Comment: Alright thanks, I edited my question. Basically i've been having trouble from the start getting the string into an actual file, so if you have any thoughts feel free to post an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After talking to another developer, he gave me this solution which I found to be a better for my situation, since the file did not exist already. It skips writing the string to a Tempfile and uses StringIO to upload it directly. His solution:

The Net::FTP#putbinaryfile method takes the *name* of a file on the local filesystem to copy to the remote filesystem. Now, if your data is in a string (and wasn't read from a file on the filesystem) then you may want to use Net::FTP#storbinary instead:

```
require 'stringio'
require 'net/ftp'

BLOCKSIZE = 512 
data      = StringIO.new("Hello, world!\n")
hostname  = "ftp.domain.tld"
username  = "username"
password  = "password"

remote_filename = "something.txt"

Net::FTP.open(hostname, username, password) do |ftp|
  # ...other ftp commands here...
  ftp.storbinary("STOR #{remote_filename}", data, BLOCKSIZE)
  # ...any other ftp commands...
end
```

The above avoids writing data that's not on disk to disk, just so you can upload it somewhere. However, if the data is already in a file on disk, you might as well just fix your code to reference its filename instead.

Comment: Nice! This is an improvement over Tempfile.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should cover most of the bases:

```
require 'tempfile'

temp_file = Tempfile.new('for_you')
temp_file.write(string)
temp_file.close

ftp.putbinaryfile(temp_file)

temp_file.unlink
```

Using Tempfile relieves you from a lot of issues regarding unique filename, threadsafeness, etc.  Garbage collection will ensure your file gets deleted, even if putbinaryfile raises an exception or similar perils.

The uploaded file will get a name like `for_you.23423423.423.423.4`, both locally and on the remote server.  If you want it to have a specific name on the remote server like 'daily_log_upload', do this instead:

```
ftp.putbinaryfile(temp_file, 'daily_log_upload')
```

It will still have a unique name for the local temp file, but you don't care about that.

Comment: I believe you mean `ftp.putbinaryfile( temp_file.path )`, correct?

Comment: I tried both and it works either way - so it apparently knows how to check if it's a File objet as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like the Tempfile solution as well

Comment: Not an answer to the question.. this persists the file.. Temp or not it writes to disk.